# Ruby: uninitialized constant Config (NameError)

Tags: ruby, rubygems, radiant

i've tried to install missing gem

```
$> bundle install
```

and got error because of installing below gem

```
sudo gem install bluecloth -v '2.1.0'
```

> --ruby=/Users/raksa/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/bin/
>   $(RUBY_BASE_NAME) extconf.rb:7:in `main': uninitialized constant Config (NameError)
>   Did you mean?  RbConfig
>                  CONFIG
>
> extconf failed, exit code 1

is anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Don't use `sudo` to install gems on Mac OS. Use either rbenv or RVM to manage a local Ruby sandbox, which you'll be able to modify easily.

Comment: ok it works for me now by downgrading version of ruby to 2.0.0

Answer (score 0):

please try installing latest version of gem by doing

```
gem install bluecloth
```

or update the `Gemfile` with

```
gem 'bluecloth', '~> 2.2'
```